# Extend Width In Both Directions

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm am trying to animate a box width to extend in both left and right direction.
Of course it's only extending in the right direction, how would I have it extend in both. Most WPF codes are in C# so I can't really find an answer from Google.

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Class MainWindow
    Private Sub EnlargeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles EnlargeBtn.Click

        Dim NewWidth = 300
        Dim widthAnimation As New DoubleAnimation(NewWidth, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
        Box.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, widthAnimation)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Put `Box` in a Grid and set its `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, had to set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center` and move the left and right margins by half the width

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Class MainWindow
    Private Sub EnlargeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles EnlargeBtn.Click

        Dim NewWidth = 300
        Dim widthAnimation As New DoubleAnimation(NewWidth, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        Dim marginAnimation As New ThicknessAnimation(New Thickness(Box.Margin.Left - NewWidth / 2, Box.Margin.Top, Box.Margin.Right - NewWidth / 2, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        Box.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, widthAnimation)
        Box.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, marginAnimation)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to animate the left position as well as the width.

If you can change the left position you'll need to change the width by twice the amount you're changing the left property by to get the box to grow uniformly in both directions.

If you can't change the left or X property of a `Rectangle` (because it doesn't appear to have one you can access - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)) then the only solution might be to put it inside another container (a Grid or Border) and set it's `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`.

Comment: How though, I tried animating the margins, but that doesn't work, and I can't find a left property for the box.

Comment: @Porkchops - What type is `Box`?

Comment: @Porkchops - Most odd, I could have sworn there was a `Left` or `X` property on a `Rectangle`.

Comment: Not that I can find one in a WPF application.

Comment: Nothing happens when setting the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`.

Comment: @Porkchops - if the margins are explicitly set then that would explain that behaviour.